# Update an AlertDialog with success or fail message after network communication

Tags: flutter, dart

1. Summarize the Problem:

My application sends information to a server and the server responds with success or failure. I am having trouble updating an `AlertDialog` with the result of network communication. I am sending multiple items to the server when the user saves their settings and I need to track if all the settings were successfully sent. So when all the settings were successfully sent, I can update the `AlertDialog` with success. The issue I am seeing with current implementation is it takes me two times to activate the `TextButton` before I see the correct message. *`AlertDialog` should show the correct message after the first `TextButton` press labeled as "save"*. One of the cases I need to solve is if the server is down and the app's connection request times out. Then I need to use something like a `CircularProgressIndicator` so the user can wait while network communication is being done.

The variable `successPrompt` is what contains the message with the result of the network transaction. This needs to be updated to the correct message by the time the `AlertDialog` pops up.

2: What I've tried:

I've tried using `FutureBuilder` to create the `AlertDialog` but I got the same result. I need a way to bring up the `AlertDialog` when I know the result of the network transaction. What happens is the `AlertDialog` will be brought up but the application is still trying to connect to the server in the background. I want to bring up the widget once this step is done and the socket is closed.

3: Here's the relevant code. Please don't mind the debug prints and commented out code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'globals.dart';
import 'dart:convert' show utf8;

import 'package:local_auth/local_auth.dart';

class SystemsSettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final int index;
  SystemsSettingsPage({ required this.index});

  @override
  _SystemsSettingsPage createState() => _SystemsSettingsPage();

}

class _SystemsSettingsPage extends State<SystemsSettingsPage> {

  bool tileValTemp = false;
  bool tileValDetect = false;
  bool tileValCamOff = false;
  bool tileValSystem = false;
  bool connected = false;

  int successCount = 0;
  String successPrompt = "";


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          title: Text("Base Station Settings"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget> [
            SwitchListTile(value: tileValDetect,
                onChanged: (bool val){ setState(() {
                  tileValDetect = val;
                });},
                title: Text('Detection notifications', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
            ),
            SwitchListTile(value: tileValTemp,
                onChanged: (bool val){ setState(() {
                  tileValTemp = val;
                });},
                title: Text('Temperature threshold out of range', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: const Text("save", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
              style: ButtonStyle(foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
                padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blueAccent)),
                onPressed: () {

                  //successPrompt = "Loading.. Wait 5 seconds to update.";
                  successCount = 0;

                  Socket.connect(baseStationAddresses[0], baseStationPort,timeout: Duration(seconds: 5)).then(
                    (socket) {
                      print('Connected to: '
                          '${socket.remoteAddress.address}:${socket
                          .remotePort}');

                      String command = "SETSYSTEM," + baseStationNames[0] + ",detectMotion," + "$tileValDetect";
                      socket.write(command);

                      socket.listen((data) {

                        String socketData = utf8.decode(data);

                        if(socketData == "REQUEST_CONFIRMED") {
                          successCount += 1;
                        }
                      },
                        onDone: () {
                          socket.destroy();
                        },

                      );
                    },
                  ).catchError((onError) {
                    print("here 1");
                    successPrompt = "There was a problem. Please retry.";

                  });

                  Socket.connect(baseStationAddresses[0], baseStationPort,timeout: Duration(seconds: 5)).then(
                          (socket) {
                        print('Connected to: '
                            '${socket.remoteAddress.address}:${socket
                            .remotePort}');

                        String command = "SETSYSTEM," + baseStationNames[0] + ",tempThreshold," + "$tileValTemp";
                        socket.write(command);

                        socket.listen((data) {
                          String socketData = utf8.decode(data);

                          if(socketData == "REQUEST_CONFIRMED") {
                            successCount += 1;
                          }
                        },
                          onDone: () {
                            print("SuccessCount $successCount");

                            if(successCount == 2)
                            {
                              print("here 2");
                              successPrompt = "Setting successfully saved.";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              print("here 3");
                              successPrompt = "Couldn't save, please retry.";
                            }

                            socket.destroy();
                          },
                        );
                      }
                  ).catchError((onError) {
                    print("here 4");
                    successPrompt = "There was a problem. Please retry.";

                  });

                  showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) =>
                      AlertDialog(
                        title: Text("Save results"),
                        content: Text(successPrompt),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                          TextButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                            child: const Text("OK"),
                          )
                        ]
                    )
                  );

                  /*
                  FutureBuilder<String>(
                    future: getSaveStatus(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      String nonNullableString = snapshot.data ?? 'Error';
                      if(snapshot.hasData) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: Text("Save results"),
                          content: Text(nonNullableString),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            TextButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                              child: const Text("OK"),
                            )
                          ]
                        );
                      }
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    },
                  );*/
                }
              ),
            Center(
              child:ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text('Remove System'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
    );
  }

  Future<String> getSaveStatus() async {

    return await new Future(() => successPrompt);
  }

}
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the content of the dialog inside of a StatefulBuilder until that your AlertDialog behave as stateless widget [Refer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html):

```
await showDialog<void>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    int selectedRadio = 0;
    return AlertDialog(
      content: StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
          return Text(successPrompt);
        },
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: I have tried this. Same result. I will try to see what else I may do.

Comment: I added showDialog() within the onPressed method for the TextButton. I think I need to restructure the code in some way. Not sure yet.

Comment: I got it. I had to wrap the portion of the network communication code with StateBuilder then use the setState() method to update the text. It's still a bit gimmicky but it's working. Thank you!